# iPhone dev: Trying to compare current date and date of array element

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, xml-parsing

I have a working UITable with sections. The UITable gets its data from an external XML file this also works good. But what I want is that the XMLparser excludes the rows where the date is older then today. I thought to do this at the moment where my file adds an element to my array. But when I add this code I get an error.
Please help me out on this one!

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
   NSDateFormatter* nsformatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
   [nsformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
   NSDate* stageDate = [XMLParser dateFromString:aStage.end];

   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Stages"])
   {
       return;
   }
   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Month"])
   {
   [appDelegate.stages addObject:aMonth];
       [aMonth release];
   aMonth = nil;
   }
   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Stage"])
   {
       /* THIS IS THE PART I ADDED BUT GIVES THE ERROR
       if(stageDate < date)
       {
       */
           [aMonth.stagesPerMonth addObject:aStage];
           [aStage release];
           aStage = nil;
       /*
       }
       */
   }
   else
   {
       [aStage setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
       [currentElementValue release];
       currentElementValue = nil;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the dates in wrong way. Try this.

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:stageDate];
if (interval > 0) {
    [aMonth.stagesPerMonth addObject:aStage];
    [aStage release];
    aStage = nil;
}
```

Comment: HI I insert your code but I am still getting an error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Stage 0x4b694f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Month.'

Comment: In which line? There might be problems other than comparing the date. Can you run the code without the date comparing part?

Comment: And what is aMonth.stagesPerMonth and aStage?

Comment: Without the date comparing part it works perfectly with the comparing part it gives the error when compiling. On line "[aStage setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];" with argument: 'Program received signal: "SIGABRT"'. It is almost like without the comparison it knows what 'elementName' is and with the comparison it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: aMonth.stagesPerMonth is an array aStage's. What it does is it has an array of array's which is provided to the Tableview. aMonth->Section, aStage-> Row. But this works all fine it is the moment that I add the comparison code when it freaks out.

Comment: Well, it is not crashing in the comparing part. Is it possible that releasing aStage and setting it to nil when the condition is true is making the crash during next call?

Comment: Bingo I had to place the [aStage release]; aStage = nil; outside of this if statement. Many thanks Man!!!

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use `NSDate`'s `compare` method:

```
NSComparisonResult result = [stageDate compare:aDate];  
if (result == NSOrderedAscending)     
    // stageDate is in the future
else if (result == NSOrderedDescending)     
    // stageDate is in the past
else     
    // Both dates are the same
```